# Is there any method to match tabular list with pivot list format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 set of data, 1 table is in pivot list format and the criteria to match is if the Color - pink, yellow, blue, red matches the column of the M list, then get the Code number, the data is as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'M': ['M1','M2','M3','M4','M5','M6','M7','M8','M9','M10'],
                    'Color' : ['pink','yellow','yellow','yellow','blue','pink','pink','pink','red','blue']})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'M_list': ['M3','M73','M18','M12','M1','M2','M7','M5','M17','M18','M20','M78','M4','M6','M8','M10','M99','M9'],
                    'pink': [23255,1755,7897,6666,1311,78946,44893,148791,18783,487913,79815,88888,149643,154894,165496,1351979,15648,5222],
                    'yellow': [1000,99999,78945,15543,10000,20000,14613,77778,45139,11776,78,1231,789613,10009,70009,88009,13036,789746],
                    'blue': [2000,8000,9000,6000,104560,204890,146103,70078,40009,11006,78789,13531,71113,10809,70999,889,36,7846],
                    'red': [300000,82200,90,60330,11560,21120,14783,1578,31109,91006,9719,9131,1113,1009,799,871,10116,1146]})

OUTPUT:
df
     M   Color
0   M1    pink
1   M2  yellow
2   M3  yellow
3   M4  yellow
4   M5    blue
5   M6    pink
6   M7    pink
7   M8    pink
8   M9     red
9  M10    blue

df1
 M_list     pink  yellow    blue     red
0    M3    23255    1000    2000  300000
1   M73     1755   99999    8000   82200
2   M18     7897   78945    9000      90
3   M12     6666   15543    6000   60330
4    M1     1311   10000  104560   11560
5    M2    78946   20000  204890   21120
6    M7    44893   14613  146103   14783
7    M5   148791   77778   70078    1578
8   M17    18783   45139   40009   31109
9   M18   487913   11776   11006   91006
10  M20    79815      78   78789    9719
11  M78    88888    1231   13531    9131
12   M4   149643  789613   71113    1113
13   M6   154894   10009   10809    1009
14   M8   165496   70009   70999     799
15  M10  1351979   88009     889     871
16  M99    15648   13036      36   10116
17   M9     5222  789746    7846    1146
```

My desire outcome will be like below:

similar to excel formula: **if("ColorB1" ="Pink",VLOOKUP(M1,df1,2,0),if("ColorB1" ="Yellow",VLOOKUP(M1,df1,3,0))........**

```
     M   Color   Code
0   M1    pink   1311
1   M2  yellow   20000
2   M3  yellow   1000
3   M4  yellow   789613
4   M5    blue   70078
5   M6    pink   154894
6   M7    pink   44893
7   M8    pink   165496
8   M9     red   1146
9  M10    blue   889
```

can i know is there any pandas method to match this?

**EDITED:**
and also what if we need to search the 'M' in 2 different M_List of df1? as below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'M_list_1': ['S3','M73','M18','M12','M1','M2','M7','S5','S17','S18','S20','M78','Z4','M6','S8','M10','M99','S9'],
                    'M_list_2': ['M3','Z73','Z18','Z12','K1','S2','Z7','M5','M17','M18','M20','M78','M4','Z6','M8','S10','M99','M9'],
                    'pink': [23255,1755,7897,6666,1311,78946,44893,148791,18783,487913,79815,88888,149643,154894,165496,1351979,15648,5222],
                    'yellow': [1000,99999,78945,15543,10000,20000,14613,77778,45139,11776,78,1231,789613,10009,70009,88009,13036,789746],
                    'blue': [2000,8000,9000,6000,104560,204890,146103,70078,40009,11006,78789,13531,71113,10809,70999,889,36,7846],
                    'red': [300000,82200,90,60330,11560,21120,14783,1578,31109,91006,9719,9131,1113,1009,799,871,10116,1146]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df2 = (df.merge(df1.melt('M_list',
               var_name='Color', 
               value_name='Code')
         .rename(columns={'M_list':'M'}), how='left', on=['M','Color']))
print (df2)
     M   Color    Code
0   M1    pink    1311
1   M2  yellow   20000
2   M3  yellow    1000
3   M4  yellow  789613
4   M5    blue   70078
5   M6    pink  154894
6   M7    pink   44893
7   M8    pink  165496
8   M9     red    1146
9  M10    blue     889
```

EDIT: You can use double `melt`:

```
df2 = (df1.melt(['M_list_1','M_list_2'], var_name='Color',  value_name='Code')
          .melt(['Color','Code'], value_name='M')
          .drop('variable', axis=1))

df = df.merge(df2, how='left', on=['M','Color'])
print (df)
     M   Color    Code
0   M1    pink    1311
1   M2  yellow   20000
2   M3  yellow    1000
3   M4  yellow  789613
4   M5    blue   70078
5   M6    pink  154894
6   M7    pink   44893
7   M8    pink  165496
8   M9     red    1146
9  M10    blue     889
```

Comment: hihi, what if need to search the 'M' from 2 different M_List of df1 yaa? i have edited in my questions, you may refer there, tq

Comment: hi, can i know must the header name must be the same? if yes, use ```.rename(columns={'':''}```? because my excel have another same column name ```pink.1, yellow.1, blue.1, red.1``` which i want to match and shows in the next column

Comment: @BBBBBBBB - Need same, becuase no match. I think this need post new question, because more complicates. Seems some duplicated columnsnames, so pandas add `.1` for all this columns